# How to change the icon of a QAction Qt on mouse hover in QToolBar element in qt?

Tags: qt, qt5.6, qaction, qtoolbar

I have some QActions in my QToolBar. QAction doesn't have any stylesheets, so I am trying to change the QAction icon on mouse hover. how can I change the QAction icon on mouse hover

Comment: I thought that QAction had a `hover()` signal you could connect to

Comment: Thankyou. Its working but when we remove the mouse hover from that action  new icon appears (mouse hovered icon appears) how can we solve that?

Comment: @RishabhBansal please show the code which partially works for you.

Comment: QAction*    m_pSettingsAction;                                                                                                                         m_pSettingsAction->setIcon(QIcon(":/settings.png"));
 connect(m_pSettingsAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(OnSettingsTriggered()));   (connect(m_pSettingsAction,SIGNAL(hovered()),this,SLOT(OnSettingsHovered()));                                                                                                  void CMainWindow::OnSettingsHovered()
{
    m_pSettingsAction->setIcon(QIcon(":/settings_active.png"));
}

Comment: I have set active icon on mouse hover. but after removing  mouse cursor(mouse hover). iT shows the active icon. but I want i should show the previous icon((QIcon(":/settings.png")))

Answer (score -1):

To change the icon on mouse hover you can set diferent pixmaps for diferent states of your QIcon, using setPixmap()

See here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#pixmap

If your action is created in QtCreator or QtDesigner, you can change it in the properties menu at property **windowIcon**

I have an action in QToolBar, that changes depending on state, so i created an QIcon and a QPixmap in the constructor, like this:

```
MainConfigWindow::MainConfigWindow(QWidget *parent) :        
    QMainWindow(parent),
    icoDisconnected(QIcon(":/icons/connect_128.png")),
    pixmapDisconnected(QPixmap(":/icons/disconnect_128.png"))
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        icoConnected.addPixmap(pixmapDisconnected,QIcon::Selected,QIcon::On);
        icoConnected.addPixmap(pixmapDisconnected,QIcon::Selected,QIcon::Off);
        icoConnected.addPixmap(pixmapDisconnected,QIcon::Active,QIcon::On);
        icoConnected.addPixmap(pixmapDisconnected,QIcon::Active,QIcon::Off);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but how do you trigger those different states by *hovering*? On some systems (eg Mac), `Active` only occurs when clicking.